# Kartik Editable Checkbox does not show default value as checked

Tags: checkbox, yii2, kartik-v

I am using Kartik/Editable of latest version.
Implemented a checkbox popup which works, but it does not show the default value as checked/unchecked.
Example:

```
echo Editable::widget([
   'name' => 'test',
   'value' => 1,
   'asPopover' => false,
   'inputType'=>Editable::INPUT_CHECKBOX,
]);
```

This will show a popover where the checkbox is not checked at all, but it should be as value = 1.
According to Kartiks documentation, the value should be an integer, not boolean.

Am I missing something? Or is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `'options' => ['checked' => true,],`  for checkbox checked.

```
Editable::widget([
        'name' => 'test',
        'value' => 1,
        'asPopover' => false,
        'options' => ['checked' => true,],
        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_CHECKBOX,
]);
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!